# DNS configuration, mount and emails

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, postfix, internal-dns

Here is a resolv.conf file that I have on a debian box (let's call it `deb01`):

```
search mydomain.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 10.20.232.11 ##local DNS server
nameserver 10.20.232.12 ##local DNS server
```

I also have another debian box, let's call it `deb02`.

My issues, seen from deb01:

1. I can't ping deb02 on the LAN (`ping deb02` returns unknown host) but `ping deb02.local`works.
2. `host deb02` or `host deb02.local` return `Host not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`
3. `nslookup deb02` or `nslookup deb02.local` don't work either
4. I can't mount a folder from deb02 on deb01 (in deb01's fstab: `deb02:/folder /mnt/myserver nfs rw 0 0` - I also tried appending `.local` but it makes no difference)
5. I have a postfix mail server that works fine

If I change the order in the resolv.conf file to place the local DNS servers first, 1, 2, 3 and 4 above work fine, using the simple server name: deb02.

But emails sent to local addresses @mydomain.com get stuck (connection timeout) although I can send emails to other domains without problems. This is probably due to the local DNS server not having any MX records.

In case it matters, the rest of the network is Windows based.

**What would be the correct DNS configuration to get 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 work, if possible using the simple server name: deb02?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a line like "`hosts: files mdns dns`" in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. This controls which sources are used for doing name lookups -- `files` tells the system to consult /etc/hosts, `mdns` uses the avahi daemon to lookup names via multicast DNS (Bonjour/ZeroConf), and `dns` is a normal DNS lookup to servers in `/etc/resolv.conf`. (Pinging `deb02.local` will likely only work when when they're on the same network together; with a router in between, or if deb02 has been turned off for a little while, it will also fail.)

`host`, `nslookup`, and `dig` are tools for doing specifically DNS queries, and bypass other methods listed in `nsswitch.conf`; `ping` will go through them all.

By default, resolv.conf entries are queried in order, moving to the next one in the list only when you get a timeout or internal error (`SERVFAIL`). A name not existing (`NXDOMAIN`) won't move you down the list. Thus, if you have an internal domain, the servers that know about it should be listed first. When that's MS Active Directory, you want to list only your MSAD DNS servers -- generally your domain controllers -- in resolv.conf.

Since it sounds like your AD domain name matches the `mydomain.com` in your search path, and your AD DNS does not present any MX records for your domain, postwill is resorting to fallback behavior of attempting to deliver to a host from a query for A records for the destination (here, `mydomain.com` itself.) An AD server will returns the set of domain controllers for that query, and AD DCs typically do not run an MTA, which is why you're seeing connection timeouts.

Typically you'll have a local mail server which you'd configure as a smarthost (`relayhost` is the postfix setting), or you can add a postfix transport rule just for mydomain.com to point to the proper mailserver for your domain.

Comment: Your assessment of the situation was spot on. In the end, I wrote an init.d script that overrides the /var/spool/postfix/etc/resolv.conf file to skip the local DNSs.